# Are chained celery tasks guaranteed to run on the same node worker?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

Are chained celery tasks guaranteed to run on the same node worker?

I know that I can build a queue for dedicated tasks, however my chain of tasks involves creating png files which need to be sent to S3. The Creation of png files is a different task in the chain so if they run in different workers the next tasks might not find the png file.

I don't want to build a seperate queue for it because otherwise I would need to run all the tasks in that particular queue and nowhere else.

```
 result = (process_diode.s() | plot_results.s() | send_to_s3.s()).apply_async()
```

In the above code if the **plot_results** task and **send_to_s3** task run in different workers than there is no guarantee that the png file will be there.

Having the guarantee that all tasks inside a chain run in the same worker node is good enough for me. Is that the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there is absolutely no such garantee. You have two solutions here: either write a single task that will do all three things at once, or use a shared filesystem to store your files.

Comment: thanks, that was my thought too, I was able to combine plot_results and sent_to_s3 tasks together by chaining them dynamically in python, then calling it eventually as a task.